# Android , connect two user in a simple online game , like tic tac toe

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

Lets say I've made a very simple game like tic-tac-toe  .
Here is the game strategy :

Firstly,  users comes in , hits the START button to start the game , 
Then I have to find another player that who is also online , then connect this two players , now , they can start the game and play around .
each player must see his opponent actions ( results ) .

**Questions** :

1 - When a user hits START , how my application should react to this  ?

I mean should I open a socket for this user ? if yes , seems that I should create a Webserver that has a Server socket , and when user connects , this webserver gets the user information , and sends him something ( I don't know what :()

2 - When another player comes to play and hits START , how should I find another player that who is also online and is ready to play and connect this two to each other so they send each other data ( like JSON data)

I don't wanna use google services , I want to build my own.
I'm ok with php, databases but not very ok with android ( I'm learning though)

I know my question is kind of broad , but I've been googling like forever , I can't get around this issue .

Can someone just tell me how can I start , I mean give me a plan , I don't need any code

Can I solve this problem by learning NodeJS ?

maybe some tutorial , a book , an example ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a very broad question.

I think it all boils down to the following issue: **how do devices send data to eachother?**

There are several options. I'm guessing you want the players to interact over the network. My suggestion is that you **use a server** as a middle man. There are several advantages to this (for example you can make the server check that the rules are indeed respected) but also disadvantages (among others, you will have to set up a server and write a server script).

At that point you can indeed use sockets for player-to-server communication. Since ultimately you can only transmit strings over the network, you will have to serialise your data, and JSON is one of many options.

If you think of it, your problem is no more complicated than a simple chat application. The server transmits data from one player to another. Take a look in that direction, such as here: http://lakjeewa.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/simple-android-client-server-application.html

Comment: You're exactly right , I want to have a middleman , but I don't now how to start , I'm ok with making a webservise RESTful api ,  but how to start ? any other tutorial ?

Comment: Lets say I made the server , android user started the game , he sent some strings to server  , waiting for another player to comes in , now , should I store that strings ( which are not valuable ) in a database so when another user comes in , show him this data ?

Comment: It depends on what you want, both options are fine. The easiest way to do it is require both users to be online all the time, and if the server can't immediately send through the data, display an error on the sender's device.

Comment: OK , so how server will send ( push ) new data to the user ? 
by using players ip ?

Comment: Google is your friend, look for push/pull methods. You now have all the leads to start, I can't program it for you ;)

Comment: @xero have you got answer? actually i also want to code of online tic tac toe game where multiple user play the game, have you any demo code?please reply me if is it possible.

Comment: @MayankSugandhi , Actually I wasn't looking for a tic tac toe and I was more looking for the solution that time , I remember I used a node js backend with socket.io and I used socket.is library in android and the rest was easy .You just open a socket and start passing data .